# Cake PHP and input field styles

Tags: css, cakephp

I have the following code in my calls/index.ctp. At the moment when I click on the comments field the cursor starts at the middle of the field and not at the very beginning and whatever is typed exceeds the field width and does not go to the next line once it has reached the field width. Can someone help? I want the cursor to start from the very beginning of the input field and if it reaches the width of the field set it should automatically go in to the next line.

calls/index.ctp:

```
<div class="divm centerdiv">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Call'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add Call Details'); ?></legend>
            <?php

        echo $this->Form->input('call_date',array('required'=>false,'id'=>'datepicker','type'=>'text'));
        echo $this->Form->input('call_time', array('required'=>false));
        echo $this->Form->input('comments', array('style'=>'width:365px; height:100px;','required'=>false, 'id'=> 'comments'));
        echo $this->Form->input('next_call_date',array('required'=>false,'id'=>'datepicker2','type'=>'text'));  echo $this->Form->input('customers_id', array('label' =>'Customer Name','options'=>$customers, 'label'=>'Customer Name', 'required'=>false));
        echo $this->Form->input('employees_id', array('label' =>'Employee name','options'=>$employees, 'label'=>'Employee name', 'required'=>false));

    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not so much a CakePHP problem, you're describing custom form behaviour on the client-side. That would require a JavaScript-based solution.

Comment: `At the moment when I click on the comments field the cursor starts at the middle of the field` Sounds like you have a css problem. Any problems which relate to the rendered result need a client side (html, css, js) fix first which *maybe* will mean you change your php code - but generally speaking how you generate html is of little relevance to html/css problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That have happened for  `style'=>'width:365px; height:100px;` this line.

Here question why?

Here you haven't increase your home size,you have increased your road!!Now you are saying why my home is small?

I Think you have used varchar and text limitation field in your database.Change varchar to text and remove the length value.Try this I think it will work fine.